Excel: How to calculate Median while excluding matching data from another column
I am trying to calculate the median time while excluding a certain data.
I have 3 columns of data.
I need to calculate the Column B but exclude times where column A & C match.



Column A
Column B
Column C




123
1:05
159


456
2:10
987


789
2:55
123


321
3:14



654
4:22



987
1:23



159
0:53



357
3:25





Try this:
=MEDIAN(IF($A:$A<>$C:$C,$B:$B))

=MEDIAN(IF((B1:B8)*(ISNA(MATCH(A1:A8,C1:C8,FALSE)))<>0,B1:B8,""))
Enter as an array formula - Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter.
The MATCH<>0 part returns an array values or NAs depending on whether there's a match - that is, it returns a value if the column A value exists in column C and returns NA if it doesn't.
The ISNA turns those in to TRUE and FALSE. A match will be FALSE because it's not NA.
B1:B8 is multiplied by the array of TRUE and FALSE where TRUE = 1 and FALSE  = 0. The IF conditional is comparing this array
{0;0.0902777777777778;0.121527777777778;0.134722222222222;0.181944444444444;0;0;0.142361111111111}
to zero. If you did the MEDIAN from there, the zeros would count. But MEDIAN ignores strings, so the IF statement turns zeros into an empty string. What ultimately gets fed into the MEDIAN function is this array
{"";0.0902777777777778;0.121527777777778;0.134722222222222;0.181944444444444;"";"";0.142361111111111}
MEDIAN ignores those three strings and returns 3:14.

I get a #value! error

if I am missing data in column B, would that give me the #value! error?

The most likely cause of a value error is that you didn't enter the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Select the cell, press F2 to edit it, then hold down Ctrl and Shift while you press enter to commit the formula. Excel will put curly braces around the formula to indicate you entered it as an array formula.
